# bash: optimizing a git-aware shell prompt

Tags: git, bash, shell

I've written the following `PS1`, which will append the current working branch to the shell prompt if I am in a git repo, and do nothing otherwise:

```
PS1='\[\e[00;32m\]\u@\h\[\e[0m\]\[\e[00;33m\] [\w]$(branch=`git symbolic-ref --short -q HEAD 2> /dev/null || git rev-parse -q --short HEAD 2> /dev/null` ; if [ $branch ] ; then echo -n -e " \e[95m<$branch>" ; fi) \[\e[00;33m\]\$\[\e[0m\] '
```

The issue is that this slows down the prompts, to the point that if I try to rapidly skip several lines, I often don't get a prompt at all.

I'm wondering if this can be optimized to run faster.  The only thing I've been able to think of is to create a wrapper around `git branch` that will print the new working branch to a file in `/repo/.git/`.  Then I could simply call `cat /repo/.git/.prompt` or something within the PS1 command. I'm not sure this would actually run faster because I'd need some logic to determine if there is a `.git` directory somewhere in the file tree, which would have it's own issues.

I don't really like this solution anyway, so I'm wondering if there is a faster way to get the current branch name from within a git repo.

NOTE: I'm aware of things like [git-aware-prompt](https://github.com/jimeh/git-aware-prompt), but I have the same issue with it.  And I could also use `$PROMPT_COMMAND`, which does run a bit faster, but it also is only capable of printing the branch name at the beginning of the prompt, which isn't really what I like.

Comment: `if [ $branch ]` is likely to cause issues.  You probably want `if [ -n "$branch" ]`

Comment: I use the [script bundled with the official git repository](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh), and it works instantly with a lot of other helpful information about the state of the repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the main benefits of `PROMPT_COMMAND` is that it allows you to build up the prompt dynamically each time it is displayed.

```
build_prompt () {
  PS1='\[\e[00;32m\]\u@\h\[\e[0m\]\[\e[00;33m\] [\w]'
  branch=$(git symbolic-ref --short -q HEAD 2> /dev/null ||
           git rev-parse -q --short HEAD 2> /dev/null)
  [[ $branch ]] &&  PS1+=" \e[95m<$branch>" 
  PS1+=' \[\e[00;33m\]\$\[\e[0m\] '
}

PROMPT_COMMAND=build_prompt
```